# My child entity is null when trying to add to a parent in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to add a bunch of children ("claims") to a parent ("matter"). But when I hit the line that says:

```
matter.Claims.Add(claim);
```

my `Claims` is null/empty.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<bool> CreateClaims(AddClaimsDataDto claimParams) 
{
    Matter matter;

    matter = await _autoContext.Matters
                               .Where(m => m.MatterNumber == claimParams.Matter)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (matter == null) 
    {
        matter = new Matter { MatterNumber = claimParams.Matter};
    }

    foreach(var trustName in claimParams.Names) 
    {
        var claim = new Claim();
        // fill claim properties here
        matter.Claims.Add(claim); // Claims is null here!
    }

    _autoContext.Matters.Add(matter);
    await _autoContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return true;
}
```

And my `Matter` entity:

```
public class Matter
{
    public Matter()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        EditedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MatterNumber { get; set; }
    public string InjuredPartyFirstName { get; set; }
    public string InjuredPartyLastName { get; set;}
    public ICollection<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime EditedDate { get; set; }
    public string EditedBy { get; set; }
}
```

My `Claim` entity:

```
public class Claim
{
    public Claim()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        EditedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ClaimNumber { get; set; }
    public Matter Matter { get; set; }
    public TrustGroup TrustGroup { get; set; } 
    public Attorney Attorney { get; set; }
    public User Contact { get; set; }
    public Status ClaimStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAttorneyApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateExported { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Injured> InjuredParty { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime EditedDate { get; set; }
    public string EditedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to Include your Claims when doing your select, like this: `matter = await _autoContext.Matters.Include(x => x.Claims) ... `
Also initializimg your property could avoid this null reference error: `public ICollection<Claim> Claims { get; set; } = new List<Claim>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update an entity framework child's list, you must eager or lazy load it before make the changes. See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

And you must also initialize the Claims property if the matter is null.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public async Task<bool> CreateClaims(AddClaimsDataDto claimParams)
{
    Matter matter;

    matter = await _autoContext.Matters
        .Include(m => m.Claims)                             //Using eager loading here
        .Where(m => m.MatterNumber == claimParams.Matter)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (matter == null) 
    {
        matter = new Matter 
        { 
            MatterNumber = claimParams,
            Claims = new List<Claim>()                      //Initialize the list here
        };
    }

    foreach(var trustName in claimParams.Names) 
    {
        var claim = new Claim();
        matter.Claims.Add(claim);
    }

    _autoContext.Matters.Add(matter);
    await _autoContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I just set it to a new instance in the constructor.